# Apache redirect for single XML file

Tags: apache, http, redirect

I have a number of subdomains, which are using [crossdomain.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174317/what-is-crossdomain-xml-file) file and I'm looking to a simple way of managing them all - which get semi-regularly updated. One way I've thought is a PHP script, which pushes and overwrites the xml file. The other, which I much prefer is a an apache redirect on a single file.

So, question is how would I, across multiple domains, redirect an xml on dom1.domain.com and dom2.wirewax.com to the same crossdomain.xml file without Flash getting upset about. i.e. not a 302 HTTP redirect, but internal file fetching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a PHP script that fetches the content from a single location (database or text file) and sends it as-is to Flash. Yes, the script itself needs to be copied on all hosts.

If you have all websites hosted on same webserver, perhaps [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) could help:

```
Alias /crossdomain.xml /path/to/shared/crossdomain.xml
```

I have not personally tested this. The reference page includes instructions to setup the shared directory so that it can be read by multiple hosts.

Comment: The file literally needs to be called crossdomain.xml (Flash has this hard coded to request from root URL) so it can't be parsed by PHP without being explicitly .php, no?

Comment: You can add a simple `RewriteRule ^crossdomain\.xml$ crossDomainGrabberScript.php` in the appropriate .htaccess file.