# If cross-browser requests are forbidden, how do I enable API access?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am writing a C# web service that serves data from a back-end web server. If I want to let other users query this service using client-side code, how would I provide them with API access?

For instance, currently the web service is on Domain1.com. Now, if I want to let someone from Domain2.com access my API using jQuery, how would I do it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174317/what-is-crossdomain-xml-file

Comment: CORS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the JSONP spec to return your data rather than JSON only. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ for full details on how jQuery handles JSONP.