# Cross-Origin Request Blocked for API Request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, cors

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at API URL. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

I have installed **Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors** in API project, but still it's not working.

Also modified web.config for Access control but not successful.

Is there any way to call API from javascript?

Comment: What is in your cross-domain policy XML file?

Comment: No, Its json format.

Comment: I have also tried that, but not working.
Do i need to recycle application pool.

Comment: @user3224493 I don't think the cross-domain configuration can be in JSON. Look at this: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/articles/crossdomain_policy_file_spec.html and also at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174317/what-is-crossdomain-xml-file

Comment: Could you attach code lines with your api method and enabling CORS. Have you tested api call in different browsers?

Comment: you need to write code to enable cors in webapi2, can you share your code where you are trying to do that

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add this code in web.config of Api.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
 </httpProtocol>
```

Comment: That block of code must be added to the <system.webServer> section of web.config